# How to get the Debug.WriteLine?

Tags: debugging

is there a possibility to get all things that are write in Debug.WriteLine in a TextBox or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's conceivably possible to write a custom trace listener that could do this.

Alternatively, why not explore something like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) -- this gives some very flexible approaches to logging that are much more sophisticated than the default logging in the framework. It can even send its output over UDP to an external listener...

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You can implement your own [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) class and direct the output to any textWriter

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that inherits from [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx), and add an instance of that class to the [Debug.Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) collection.